# SQL Server 2012 Express checking and silent installation

Tags: installshield, sql-server-2012-express

We need to perform the following using InstallShield 2013, can someone please guide me:

1. Check if SQL Server Express is installed in the user's machine or not.
2. If present, what is the version that is present.
3. If the version is not 2012, then we need to install SQL Server Express 2012 silently in the background.
4. Give write access on a folder for a particular login (Sql service)
5. After installation of SQL Express 2012, we need to restore a database from a .bak file.
6. After restoring the db, how to run some sql scripts?

Please provide me any link or guidance on how to acheive the above objectives. I am also parallely trying to read the documentation and blogs, but they are vast.

Thanks in advance,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve it. You can do a check using prerequisite and get it installed. You can use custom action or install script to do the silent install of SQL server after doing registry check.

once installed, using the script you can restore the database, and installshiled basic msi provides options to include the sql scripts and run it or using the installscript you can run the sql scripts .